# How to add Cordova 3.1.0 platform

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugin-proguard

I get an error trying to add a platform to cordova

LOG Output

```
D:\hello>cordova platform add android -d
cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
Checking Android requirements...
Running "android list target" (output to follow)
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-17"
     Name: Android 4.2.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 17
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, W
XGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 2 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 1
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, W
XGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a

Running "android update project -p "C:\Users\Alen\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3
.1.0\framework" -t android-17" (output to follow)...
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
build.xml: Found version-tag: custom. File will not be updated.
Updated file C:\Users\Alen\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\framework\proguard
-project.txt

Creating android project...
Running bin/create for platform "android" with command: ""C:\Users\Alen\.cordova
\lib\android\cordova\3.1.0\bin\create"  "D:\hello\platforms\android" "com.exampl
e.hello" "HelloWorld"" (output to follow)

Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

    at C:\Users\Alen\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:24
6:30
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

There was a problem with the sdk Path before. I think i fixed it.

I doubt that there is a problem with the and

when i enter >java in CLI it shows up

when i enter >ant says 'ant' is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i enter >ant says 'ant' is not recognized.

You need to downlaod, install, and add `ant` to your path.